# $[object Object]-$[object Object] Couldn't retrieve the value

Tags: jquery

I have a problem where I couldn't retrieve the slider value when I load the page, it just shows me $[object Object]-$[object Object]. How do I fixed the code?

```
$( function(){
$("#slider-range").slider({
   range:true,
   min:0.00,
   max:499.00,
   values:[0.00, 499.00],
   slide: function(event, ui){
       $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "-$" + ui.values[1]);
   }
});
$("#amount").val("$" + $("slider-range").slider("values",0) + "-$" + $("slider-range").slider("values", 1));
```

Comment: `$("slider-range")` is not a valid selector, I suppose you mean `$("#slider-range")` instead?

Comment: I think we have `ui.value` instead of `ui.values` to make sure just do `console.log(ui)` that will give you the clear picture.

Comment: @ShaileshRathod u mean console.log(ui) where should I place it?

Comment: @empiric I'm using $("#slider-range")

Comment: instead `$("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "-$" + ui.values[1]);` you get the value in browser inspector

Comment: @billy you are not for the last row of your code, but nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this..

```
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 499,
      values: [ 0, 499],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```